# Multiple Select box with values pre selected in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Ive been working on implementing acts-as-taggable-on and select2 to get a tagging system similar to here on stackoverflow.  I finally got everything to work but there is two issues I can figure out.

1. How to have tags already saved pre-populated
2. When I first load the page it doesn't apply the select2 javascript on the initial load but if I refresh the page it formats it correctly with the select2 javascript. (using coffee so might switch to regular javascript)

Heres the two chunks of code that apply:

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
    $("select#cuisine-select").select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
        placeholder: 'Select Cuisine'
        allowClear: true
    });
```

The form code:

```
<div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :cuisine_list, "Cuisines (separated by commas)" %>
    <%= f.collection_select :cuisine_list, Recipe.cuisine_counts, :id, :name, {},
                    { multiple: true, id: "cuisine-select", :style => "width:300px"} %>
</div>
```

EDIT: Solved part of this but now when I load the edit it loads correctly but when I update it updates with the ids and not the name.  This is what I changed it to:

```
<div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :cuisine_list, "Cuisines (separated by commas)" %>
    <%= f.collection_select :cuisine_list, Recipe.cuisine_counts, :id, :name, {:selected => recipe.cuisine_counts.map(&:id)},
                        { multiple: true, id: "cuisine-select", :style => "width:300px"} %>
</div>
```

Also I changed the page:load to turbolinks:load and that seems to have fixed the problem with it not loading on the initial visit.